# c# string sorting VS Oracle string sorting

Tags: c#, oracle, sorting

I have to sort a list of strings in exactly the same way as they are returned to me from an oracle database. Unfortunately Oracle returns them in such a way, that numeric characters are sorted after alphabetic. For example:

```
Alabama
x-men
100 new ideas
9 months
...
```

How could I sort a list of strings in C# in such a way?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle can sort in several ways. By default Oracle will sort strings (VARCHAR) in a binary way, ie: strings will be sorted by the numeric values of each character in the database character set.

```
SQL> select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter like '%SORT%';

PARAMETER  VALUE
---------- ----------
NLS_SORT   BINARY

SQL> SELECT rownum, chr(ROWNUM) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 127 ORDER BY 2;

    ROWNUM CHR(ROWNUM)
---------- -----------
[...]
        48 0
        49 1
        50 2
        51 3
[...]
        65 A
        66 B
        67 C
        68 D
[...]
        97 a
        98 b
        99 c
```

You can alter the sorting behaviour:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort=french;

Session altered

SQL> SELECT rownum, chr(ROWNUM) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 127 ORDER BY 2;

    ROWNUM CHR(ROWNUM)
---------- -----------
[...]
        65 A
        97 a
        66 B
        98 b
[...]
        90 Z
       122 z
        48 0
        49 1
        50 2
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom class derived from [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) to exactly replicate the results.

However, Oracle's string sorting likely is determined by the collation used in the database/table/query so when using the same culture for sorting you *may* get the same results already without resorting to writing too much on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own IComparer class, and use that instance to sort your list of strings.

`List<T>` has a member method 'Sort' which takes an IComparer or Comparision, in which you can implement your order-logic.